# Conexion PostgreSQL con C#

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

a continuacion les dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando para conectarme e insertar registros en mi base de datos

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=demoluis;User Id=Luis;Password=micontraseña;");
        conn.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand Command = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into nombres values(" + textBox1.Text + ")",conn);
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        textBox1.Clear();
        conn.Close();
```

el problema es que al momento de tratar de insertar un registro en mi base de datos mi tira los siguientes errores de los cuales no entiendo a que se pueda deber

```
{"28P01: la autentificaci�n password fall� para el usuario �Luis�"}
{"No password has been provided but the backend requires one (in MD5)"}
```

esto sucede cuando quito y pongo la contraseña...

cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando  npgsql , Mono.Security con las versiones mas estables y recientes

pd: si me preguntan por que solo tengo una tabla es por que solo estoy practicando pero este error no se como solucionarlo...

Comment: Hola @Jeff, ¿el usuario y la contraseña de esat base de datos son esos? para esa BD y ese usuario la contraseña es: micontraseña (con la ñ) ?

Comment: *esto sucede cuando quito y pongo la contraseña...*: ¿Qué quieres decir con esto? Sospecho que no estás mostrando el código que produce el error en cuestión.  Por favor incluye el error completo con el stack trace (pila de llamadas) y un [mcve].